# How do I get the image of the UIContextualAction button to display properly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sketchapp, uicontextualaction

I made an image for the button of a UIContexualAction using sketch but when I loaded the image onto a tableViewCell, the image turned out like below.

This is the code that was added to the UIContextualAction.

```
       let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Guestlist") { (action, actionView ,completion) in

        completion(true)
        }
    action.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "GuestList")
  //  action.backgroundColor = .purple
    return action
}
```

[image: UIContexualAction Button Image]

Comment: Can you include your code that adds the action in the question. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check real solution for this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53186374/3940673